# Error injecting @Injectable() into another @Injectable()

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having trouble with Angular2 DI. I try to inject a class into another and it raises the following error:

Message: `"Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ProductService'(undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ProductService' is decorated with Injectable."`

Full stack: `"BaseException@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:3776:27NoAnnotationError@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4480:13_extractToken@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5027:19_dependenciesFor/<@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4979:49_dependenciesFor@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4979:16resolveReflectiveFactory@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4872:28resolveReflectiveProvider@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4895:84resolveReflectiveProviders@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4902:24ReflectiveInjector</ReflectiveInjector.resolve@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5376:20ReflectiveInjector</ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5406:47bootstrap@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:468:27@http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:12:1@http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:1:1@http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:1:1bootstrap/</</__exec@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:1506:1bootstrap/</</</</entry.execute@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:3921:11linkDynamicModule@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:3247:18link@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:3090:11bootstrap/</</</</</<.execute@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:3427:13doDynamicExecute@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:796:20link@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:998:20doLink@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:650:7updateLinkSetOnLoad@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:698:18proceedToTranslate/</<@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1465996676353:510:11Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:323:20Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:216:25scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:571:53Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:356:24Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:256:29drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:474:26ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:5555/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1465996676355:426:22`

The weird thing here is I got both classes, the one being injected and the one receiving the injection, decorated with `@Injectable()`. Relevant code as follows:

`main.ts`:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { MarkdownService } from './shared/index';
import {
  ProductService,
  WidgetService,
  WidgetItemService
} from './services/index';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

if ('<%= ENV %>' === 'prod') { enableProdMode(); }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  ProductService, WidgetService, WidgetItemService, MarkdownService,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' })
]);
```

`widget-item.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product, Widget, WidgetItem } from '../index';

@Injectable()
export class WidgetItemService {
  private widget_items: Array<WidgetItem> = [];

  getAll(key: string = null): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.widget_items);
  };

  constructor() {
  };
};
```

`product.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product, WidgetItem, WidgetItemService } from '../index';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  getWidgetItems(product_id: number) {
    var widget_items: WidgetItem[] = [];

    this.widgetItemService.getAll().then((found_widget_items: WidgetItem[]) => {
      widget_items = found_widget_items.filter(widget_item => widget_item.product_id == product_id);
      return Promise.resolve(widget_items);
    }).catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
  }

  constructor(
    private widgetItemService: WidgetItemService
  ) {
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you have this error when the imports aren't correct regarding types of parameters you want to use in the constructor.

You should check this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product, WidgetItem, WidgetItemService } from '../index';

console.log(WidgetItemService); // <----

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    private widgetItemService: WidgetItemService
  ) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, I got an `undefined` output. Am I missing something from the service lifecycle?